# How add new column to existing database on asset folder in android app?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I wrote an application that use data from existing database on asset folder. for copy and use data I wrote following ExternalOpenDbHelper:

```
public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DB_PATH;

    private static String TABALE_NAME = "font";
    private static String FONT_ID = "_id";
    private static String FONT_TYPE = "font_type";
    private static String FONT_SIZE = "font_size";

    private static String POEM_TABLE = "poem";
    private static String POEM_ID = "_id";
    private static String READ_POINT = "read_point";
    private static String BOOKMARK = "bookmark";

    public static String DB_NAME;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public final Context context;
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return database;
    }

    public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;

        String packageName = context.getPackageName();

        DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
        DB_NAME = databaseName;
        openDataBase();
    }

    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }
        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        return database;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE cat ADD point BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;");
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE poem ADD read_point BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false;");
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE poem ADD bookmark INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;");
        }
    }

    public int updateFont(int i, String fontName, int p) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues font = new ContentValues();
        font.put(FONT_TYPE, fontName);
        font.put(FONT_SIZE, p);

        String whereClause = FONT_ID + " LIKE ?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(i) };

        return db.update(TABALE_NAME, font, whereClause, whereArgs);
    }

    public void updateReadPoint(int poemId, int readPointTeransfer) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String whereClause;
        String[] whereArgs;

        if (poemId != readPointTeransfer) {
            ContentValues readPoint = new ContentValues();
            readPoint.put(READ_POINT, Boolean.toString(true));

            whereClause = POEM_ID + " LIKE ?";
            whereArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(poemId) };

            db.update(POEM_TABLE, readPoint, whereClause, whereArgs);

            if (readPointTeransfer != -1) {
                readPoint.put(READ_POINT, Boolean.toString(false));
                whereArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(readPointTeransfer) };
                db.update(POEM_TABLE, readPoint, whereClause, whereArgs);
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateBookmarkList(int i, String idOfThisPoem) {


        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues bookmarkValue = new ContentValues();
        String whereClause = POEM_ID + " LIKE ?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { idOfThisPoem };
        if (i == 0) {

            bookmarkValue.put(BOOKMARK, Integer.toString(0));
            db.update(POEM_TABLE, bookmarkValue, whereClause, whereArgs);
        } else if (i == 1) {

            bookmarkValue.put(BOOKMARK, Integer.toString(1));
            db.update(POEM_TABLE, bookmarkValue, whereClause, whereArgs);
        }
    }

    public boolean bookmarkStatus(String idOfThisPoem){
        String idOfThisBookmarkedPoem = null;
        Boolean iconFull = null;

        String[] tableColumns = new String[] { POEM_ID, BOOKMARK };
        String whereClause = POEM_ID + " LIKE ?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { idOfThisPoem };
        Cursor poetCursor = database.query(POEM_TABLE, tableColumns,
                whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, POEM_ID);

        poetCursor.moveToFirst();
        if (!poetCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {

                idOfThisBookmarkedPoem = poetCursor.getString(1);

            } while (poetCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        poetCursor.close();

        if (Integer.valueOf(idOfThisBookmarkedPoem) == 0) {
            iconFull = false;

        } else if (Integer.valueOf(idOfThisBookmarkedPoem) == 1) {
            iconFull = true;

        }
        return iconFull;
    }

}
```

In my code I checked if the data was copied on the phone don't copy again but if there wasn't on the path it copy from asset folder and read/write on the copied database on phone. I can't copy database from asset every time that app get run because I just write on the database that (//data//data//%s//databases//). Now I need to add new columns on two table of it and because  I released it before don't like end user uninstall and install the app again. I try and googled lots of job but couldn't find solution. I guess if I could remove data on (//data//data//%s//databases//) path could do it right.

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper instead of some broken code based on a very old blog post.

Comment: thank you, but I can't understand your means. You say I selected wrong path in my code and must change it to the code on github?

Answer (score 0):

> How add new column to existing database on asset folder in android app?

You cannot modify an asset.

You are welcome to modify your local copy of the database, by calling `execSQL()` on a `SQLiteDatabase` object and executing an `ALTER TABLE` statement.

I echo laalto's comment: please [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). Among other things, it gives you multiple ways of adding new columns to an existing database.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I do this means I added new columns in asset database and change DATABASE_VERSION  to two and on Upgrade method wrote alter table instructions but it doesn't work for me because I can't remove the (if (!dbExist) ) on oncreate method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to version control your database. In other words, you don't seem to do any checks for the current version when you open the DB.

For example, you define the current version:

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

But you must add a preference (`SharedPreferences`) or something similar to save the version of the DB that is installed on the user's device when the DB is installed. Then in later updates you can change the version and add code to update the DB to the new version. Since you haven't done this yet you will also need to check for the case where no version is identified.

To perform the upgrade, use the `ExternalDbOpenHelper` constructor or a method like`openDataBase` or even `checkDataBase` to do your version check by calling `onUpgrade` with the current DB version and the installed DB version.

Like this:

```
    onUpgrade(database, settings.getInt(OLD_DB_VERSION, 0), DATABASE_VERSION);
```

You must also remember to save the new DB version after you perform an update or when a new install occurs.